# httpagility pack scraping between broken tag

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, http, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i need to scrape a p tag which has h3 tag after it but does not have a closing p tag.     It looks like this :

```
<script ad>asdasdasd</script>
<p>Translation companies are
-----------------------
-----------------------
<h3 class="this_class">mind blown site</h3>
```

There is no </p> tag so i cannot parse it completely. Now i have two questions :

1) can this be parsed using httpagility xpath ?

2) i have a function to find text between two strings (getbetween). But i have a doubt - If i use "asdasdasd" and " is it always 100% that vb.net will use the script tag which is just above h3 because there are 2-3 same lines - "asdasdasd"

3) Any other method you guys are aware of ?

(had to write in code so html does not mess up)

Regards,

Comment: The html specification states that the end tag </p> is optional so this is not an error although, in recent years, authors seem much better at including optional end tags.  Paragraphs cannot be nested so the <p> is terminated by the next block level element's start tag.  If the paragraph does not include inline elements, picking up the next < would do.  Failing that, you will have to classify tags as block or inline and search for the next block tag.

Comment: I replaced your </p> by &lt;/p> so your paragraph tag was not picked up as html. This may be a useful point for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good idea to post some more "real" html to really help you, at least the tags between the `h3` and the `p`.
Anyway, this should get you the `p`-Tag from the `h3-`Tag.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(... //Load the Html...

//Either of these lines will do
HtmlNode pNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[@class='this_class']/preceding-sibling::p");
//HtmlNode pNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[contains(text(),'mind blown site')]/preceding-sibling::p");

string pInnerHtml = pNode.NextSibling.InnerHtml; //Has the text "Translation companies are...."
```

Comment: yup the first one worked. and there is no html between p and h3. well my boss happy so who cares. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

So in general, to get all the nodes from the opening `p` tag to the start of a tag you don't want, you could do this:

```
var p = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p");
var h3 = p.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::h3[@class='this_class']");
var following = new List<string>();
for (var current = p.NextSibling; current != h3; current = current.NextSibling)
{
    following.Add(current.InnerText);
}
var innerText = String.Concat(following);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for answer but i need the p tag and not the h3 tag. can you tell me how to get the preceding element ? Anything the opposite of following sibling? Regards

Comment: This does get the `h3` tag.  It just uses the `p` tag as a reference.

Comment: lol i know this gets the h3 tag. but i want the p tag content and not H3. Is there any way to access P tag using h3? I want "translation companies are"  Regards

Comment: Oh duh, well sorry, the question sounded like you needed the `h3`.  Technically, the `p` tag is empty so what you've been saying confused me.  Depending on what comes between the opening `p` tag and the `h3`, you should be able to just get the `p`, then get the next sibling if the text you want is just one complete body.  shriek already shows that.